# React - selected value is not displayed after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm using `react-select` to let the user pick a choice from a list of options. It's supposed to update on-change. I've verified that the selected option is indeed being updated into the database, and the input is being recognized by React upon checking it in the React chrome tools. What's puzzling is how it doesn't get displayed after refreshing the page.

```
class ContractBasicForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      contractingEntity: props.contracting_entity
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      contractingEntity: nextProps.contracting_entity
    })
  }


  autoSetState = (newState) => {
    this.setState(newState)
    this.props.formSubmit()
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <section className="row ml-2 mr-2 mt-2">
          <article className="col-12 side-modal-form">
            <SelectInput
              header="Contracting Entity"
              name="contract[contracting_entity]"
              options={this.props.contracting_entity_opts}
              value={this.state.contracting_entity}
              userCanEdit={this.props.user_can_edit}
              multi={false}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.autoSetState({contracting_entity: e.value})
              }}
              />
          </article>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have another input called `Stage` which is very similar to `ContractingEntity`, but its value is displayed after refreshing the page:

```
<SelectInput
  header="Stage"
  name="contract[stage]"
  options={this.props.stage_opts}
  value={this.state.stage}
  userCanEdit={this.props.user_can_edit}
  multi={false}
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.autoSetState({stage: e.value})
  }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React app state will be initialised on page refresh. You need to persist such data in localStorage if you want to keep it after page refresh. This is considered as anti-pattern in react and it is recommended not to use this unless it becomes necessity.

I hope this made things clear for you.